# Jquery autocomplete always suggests every option

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete

It doesnt matter what i type into the textbox, always shows the whole list. Heres my code:

```
$("#tb_country").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/index.php/ajax_calls/select_countries",
      dataType: "json",
      data:  request,
      success: function(data) {
        response(data);
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 3
});
```

The **select_countries** function returns JSON data in the right format for autocomplete i.e. *[{"label":"United States"},{"label":"Canada"}........]*
Please can someone tell me whats wrong with this, thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you actually filter your response in the server-side code, as described [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

> The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query
>   string is added with a term field, which **the server-side script should
>   use for filtering the results**. For example, if the source option is
>   set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request
>   would be made to http://example.com?term=foo.

You do send the correct request (with `term` param filled by the current value of `input` element), but most probably don't use it in the server code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that response is not in context?

Instead of using response(data) u could try a onchange that fetches the data from the server and than just set the source like this:

```
$("#tb_country").autocomplete( "option", "source", serverData );
```

Also I didn't understood if the problem is in the returned data from the server or in the jquery. If the problem is the data from the server you should make sure what is being sent in the request.

Edit: Must be a server problem since data was already filled once.
Can you please please post the Request Headers and or server function?

Comment: How come `response is not in context`, if the whole list _is_ shown?

Comment: Ok than it must be a server problem. I assumed it had filled the list at least once.